Triggering JSON Event Transmission in SSM Run Command to Python File
Automate the process of triggering a Python script on an EC2 instance via AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Run Command whenever a specified AWS resource (such as S3, EC2, or IAM) is created. The Python script will receive the event details as a JSON payload.
Using lambda it is possible but how can I do this with an ec2 instance, it is not taking any event response.
using lambda it is working fine.
my code is triggering ssm run command. which is calling my python file but the output is blank.
here is my python code of lambda which i am using.
import boto3
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from io import BytesIO
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print(event)
s3 = boto3.client(‘s3’)
bucket_name = ‘task-update-excel-for-all-resources’
file_key = ‘Update the excel for all resources.xlsx’  # Your Excel file name
# Download the Excel file from S3
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
file_content = response[‘Body’].read()

# Load the workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(file_content))
sheet = workbook.active

# Get the new resource information from the CloudTrail event
new_resource_info = extract_resource_info(event)

# Update the Excel sheet (append new data)
new_row = [new_resource_info[‘resource_id’], new_resource_info[‘resource_type’], new_resource_info[‘action’], new_resource_info[‘timestamp’]]
sheet.append(new_row)

# Save the workbook to a BytesIO object
output = BytesIO()
workbook.save(output)
output.seek(0)

# Upload the updated file back to S3
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key, Body=output)

def extract_resource_info(event):
# Extract relevant information from the CloudTrail event
detail = event[‘detail’]
event_name = detail[‘eventName’]
timestamp = detail[‘eventTime’]
action = ‘Create’ if event_name.startswith(‘Create’) or event_name.startswith(‘Run’) else ‘Delete’
if event_name in [‘RunInstances’, ‘TerminateInstances’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘responseElements’][‘instancesSet’][‘items’][0][‘instanceId’]
    resource_type = ‘EC2 Instance’
elif event_name in [‘CreateBucket’, ‘DeleteBucket’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘requestParameters’][‘bucketName’]
    resource_type = ‘S3 Bucket’
elif event_name in [‘CreateUser’, ‘DeleteUser’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘requestParameters’][‘userName’]
    resource_type = ‘IAM User’
elif event_name in [‘CreateTrail’, ‘DeleteTrail’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘requestParameters’][‘name’]
    resource_type = ‘CloudTrail’
elif event_name in [‘CreateUserPool’, ‘DeleteUserPool’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘requestParameters’][‘userPoolId’]
    resource_type = ‘Cognito User Pool’
elif event_name in [‘CreateFunction’, ‘DeleteFunction’]:
    resource_id = detail[‘requestParameters’][‘functionName’]
    resource_type = ‘Lambda Function’
elif event_name.startswith(‘Create’) or event_name.startswith(‘Delete’):
    resource_id = ‘N/A’  # General case if specific ID not found
    resource_type = ‘Generic Resource’
else:
    resource_id = ‘Unknown’
    resource_type = ‘Unknown’

return {
    ‘resource_id’: resource_id,
    ‘resource_type’: resource_type,
    ‘action’: action,
    ‘timestamp’: timestamp
}

